# how to parse json response from webservice url and parse it as url in android

Tags: android, json, web-services, request

I have an application in that i called webservice using [this link](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/#comment-179),I have one webservice Url and another Url is getting as response from that url.I need to use that url as

> public static final String TIME_CENTRAL_SERVER = "http://accounts.myexample.com/Services"; in the place of 
>   "http://accounts.myexample.com/Services" i need to parse my json response.

I have check for that in google but couldn't get any answer can anyone help me regarding this, Thanks in advance.
If anyone have queries ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved my issue with guidance of my team head below is the code which we have used in constants.java class

```
public static final String GET_CENTRAL_SERVER = String.format("%s/AccountService/security/ValidateAccess", TIMEMACHINE_ACCOUNTS_SERVER);
```

and add code snippet in serversync.java class

```
public String getCentralServer(Context context, String serial_number) throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient(Constants.GET_CENTRAL_SERVER);
    client.addParam("accesscode", String.valueOf(serial_number));
    client.addParam("type", "2");
    client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
    String response = client.getResponse();
    if (response != null){
        response = response.replaceAll("\\\\/", "/");
        response = response.replace("\"", "");
        response = response.replace("\n","");
        response = "http://" + response;
        return response;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First webservice call is like below

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(LOGIN_URL);
client.AddParam("accountType", "GOOGLE");
client.AddParam("source", "tboda-widgalytics-0.1");
client.AddParam("Email", _username);
client.AddParam("Passwd", _password);
client.AddParam("service", "analytics");
client.AddHeader("GData-Version", "2");

try {
    client.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String response = client.getResponse();
```

After parsing the response, if you want to do another Web Service call, just create another object of RestClient with different URL and Parameters and call execute method, like below,

```
RestClient client1 = new RestClient(GET_INFO_URL);
client1.AddParam("userid", "123");

try {
    client1.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String response1 = client1.getResponse();
```

Comment: the above reply is not wat i want

Comment: @Html5 - Can you please provide response of first Rest Request? and then what you want to do with that request?

Comment: im getting one url as response from webservice request and i need to append that url @Amit

Comment: You mean String response = client.getResponse(); will return an URL? If that is the case, then in subsequent Rest Request, provide "response" in RestClient constructor as "RestClient client1 = new RestClient(response);"

Comment: yes im getting string as response from webservice url
can you tel me how to follow up code for that

Comment: Now is it working for you?, if yes, then I will update my answer for future reference

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27179/discussion-between-amit-and-html5)